# How can I return the value of the method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, variables

I have the following method that was returning null, trying to debug it I found out that when reaching the last line (the return), the variable to return has the expected value, but instead of exiting the method and returning the value, the code runs back into the preceding catch with "NullReferenceException" and ends up returning null after that.
This only happens when the method is called in several threads at the same time.
Can someone please explain to me why is this happening?

calling block:

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
foreach (Event eV in temp)
{
    var associatedUserEvent = new User_Event().GetItemByFilter("Event", eV.Title);
    ThreadStart c = new ThreadStart(() => xx(temp2, eV));
    Thread cT = new Thread(c);
    threads.Add(cT);
    cT.Start();
}
foreach (var cT in threads)
{
    cT.Join();
}
```

calling method:

```
public void xx(List<User_Event> temp2, Event eV)
        {
            var associatedUserEvent = new User_Event().GetItemByFilter("Event", eV.Title);
            if (associatedUserEvent != null) temp2.Add(associatedUserEvent);
        }
```

method that is running backwards:
(strings a, c and t are for debbuging purposes only)

```
public SPListItemCollection executeQuery()
    {

        SPListItemCollection toReturn = null;
        string a, t, c;

        try
        {
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                if (type.getListName() != null)
                {
                    SPList list = web.GetList(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/" + type.getListName());

                    if (filters != null || folderPath != null)
                    {

                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

                        if (customViewFields != null)
                        {
                            query.ViewFields = buildViewFields();
                            query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
                            query.IncludeMandatoryColumns = false;
                        }

                        query.IncludeAttachmentUrls = true;
                        query.Folder = web.GetFolder(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/" + type.getListName() + "/" + folderPath);
                        query.Query = this.filters != null && this.filters.Length > 0 ? this.CreateCAMLQuery() : @"<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy></Query>";
                        query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
                        toReturn = list.GetItems(query);
                        a = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        toReturn = list.GetItems(customViewFields);
                    }
                    c = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new System.ArgumentException("Custom attributte listname cannot be null");
                }

                t = "";
            });
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            a = "";
        }

        return toReturn;
    }
```

Comment: `the code runs back into the preceding catch` This probably means that the debugger has switched to another thread. Debugging multithreaded applications can be very painful.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for answering. That would be the logical conclusion but the thing is the variable toReturn holds the right value until the last line of the method, but the method is always returning null, it loses the value after entering the catch block, and it had the value before that, if debugging a different thread was the issue, at least one thread should return the value and they are all returning null. Is it possible that the thread where the method is trying to return to is null? But shouldn't that just break execution?

Comment: To confirm your thinking, you can take out treading and then debug. You can also write values to output window to check.

Comment: I think that first call to `executeQuery()` function is processed successfully but next call failed, and actually the code does not return back as you mentioned in the question (It's actually another call, you can check from Thread window in VS). I suggest to write traces in file or output window to check where is the problem.